# Is it possible to simulate a small tax change using the UK budget office business model?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy, budget

Where can I use the OBR economic model for the UK Budget?

I want to see the impact on public revenue by increasing the upper rate of income tax by 1%.

Comment: That would indeed be nice. Maybe a disclaimer: business models do not necessarily have to be accurate. There will always be some margin of error. So if the model says you'll get money in reality if the policy were to be implemented you might have to pay instead with some probability.

Comment: The purpose of such an inquiry being what? What useful function could such information be put to? If it increases revenue is that a good thing? (Spoiler: the government does not have a revenue problem, it has a spending problem.)

Comment: @BillOnne I guess the question is how much money would effectively be generated by a small but significant tax including all factors (like rich people potentially not wanting to work anymore if their wealth is taxed). It could then be part of a slogan, like XXX million pounds a week for the NHS by just 1% on the rich who could surely afford it. I can imagine. The number would then be scientifically backed up.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the macroeconomic model used by the Office for Budget Responsibility [here](https://obr.uk/forecasts-in-depth/obr-macroeconomic-model/). The code can be freely downloaded, allowing you to use it as you wish. There is also a briefing paper which discusses how the model is used.

If you are unfamiliar with the model, you may find it difficult to use. It might be easier to simply ask the OBR, or perhaps a professor of macroeconomics who regularly engages with the public, for an answer to your question.